# Handle divisor 0 error when some divisors are NULL

Tags: t-sql

I am getting dividing by 0 errors. I noticed that sometimes the field I'm dividing by is NULL.

```
(SUM(RentMonths * SQFT) / SUM(SQFT))
```

What's the proper way to handle this situation when SQFT can be null at times? I know it's probably bad data but that's besides the point; I can't fix that right now.

Answer (score 5):

Dividing by `NULL` is perfectly valid - the result is simply `NULL`. The problem is (as the error message states) when you try to divide by **zero**.

You can use [`NULLIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) to solve this problem:

```
(SUM(RentMonths * SQFT) / NULLIF(SUM(SQFT), 0))
```

The result will be `NULL` if the divisor is `0` or if either operand is `NULL`.

---

As pointed out in the comments, a `CASE` statement could also be used:

```
CASE WHEN SUM(SQFT) <> 0 THEN (SUM(RentMonths * SQFT) / SUM(SQFT)) END
```

The advantage is that this will work in almost any database, but a disadvantage is that it repeats the expression to calculate the divisor.

Comment: thanks yea the case is pretty sloppy as in readable code.  I'll try the NULLIF.

Answer (score 0):

An IF statement seems pretty appropriate here, no?

Don't know if this is correct TSQL syntax but:

```
IF @SQFT IS NOT NULL (SUM(RentMonths * SQFT) / SUM(SQFT))
```